# How do I invoke a Perl script on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I tried compile apache 2.2, my Visual Studio 2008 returned error on RC. After some googling, I found this explanation:

> What appears to have happened is that
>   you've opened it up unsuccessfully in
>   Visual Studio; before you convert to
>   an .sln file + .vcproj files, it's
>   important to invoke the perl script
>
> perl srclib\apr\build\cvtdsp.pl
>   -2005
>
> which will do evil things to the .dsp
>   file syntax, breaking them forever but
>   allowing us to work around a visual
>   studio bug.  Then, load the Apache.dsw
>   into a modern visual studio; it should
>   'just work'.

Can anyone explain to me how to invoke Perl script on Windows?

Thank you

Comment: are you trying to compile in windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two distributions of Perl for Windows that you could get are

- [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) (A new distribution that integrates a C compiler to have the CPAN archive fully working on Windows)
- [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) (The most common distribution but the CPAN doesn't work)

Just install one of them as this script doesn't seem to use any thing fancy.

Comment: Could you explain the non-working CPAN in A.Perl ? I just installed A.Perl the other day, for similar purposes as above, and although I haven't tried downloading anything from CPAN, the Package manager seems to be working.

Comment: The CPAN is a source repository, sometimes containing C source code for glue with operating system. So you need a full C compiler to use it, ActivePerl uses PPM (binary) repository instead of directly using CPAN. It doesn't contain all CPAN modules only most of them.

Comment: You can also get perl from the cygwin environment, although it's mostly designed to work within the cygwin environment and not the Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Also since it is Windows make sure the Perl interpretor is in your system path.

Comment: Oddly enough, that's a Unix requirement too! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use in my perl scripts always a short cmd file with the same name as the script to set some initial variables and call the actual script : 
The benefits ?! Portability to Unix and Linux is easier when you wrap all of the logic in the Perl script and the sh or cmd files are just setting some basic kick off vars :

Something like :

```
    set _BaseDir=E:\Perl\sfw
    set _ProjectName=logger
    set _ProjectVersion=0.6.0
    set _ProjectVersionDir=%_BaseDir%\%_ProjectName%\%_ProjectName%.%_ProjectVersion%

    set _PerlScript=%_ProjectVersionDir%\%_ProjectName%.pl
    set _CmdScript=%_ProjectVersionDir%\%_ProjectName%.cmd


    :: Action !!!
    perl %_PerlScript% 

    :: ping localhost -n 5
    pause
```